# how to make the chrome extension is to be active for any host

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm using the following code for the chrome extension is to be active for a particular host.

```
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
  conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
    pageUrl: {hostEquals: 'www.google.com'},
  })],
  actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.Sho``wPageAction()]
}]);
```

});

I want it to be active for all the hosts.

Comment: You can use `urlContains: ':'`, see [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#type-PageStateMatcher).

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks dude :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `hostContains: '.'` which activates your extension for all hosts. I've tested this and it's working for all hosts.